Why is USB redirection in wirt-manager not working as expected in ArchLinux?
Virtual Machine Manager version: 4.1.0
The USB-redirection worked without any problem or with any hack on my last installation some years ago.
I now reinstalled and it just won't work.
Read, watched vids and other stuff about this and now I found this small 'fix'.
Not what I want, but it works for now.
If I install this package: qemu-hw-usb-host and then (re)install libusb (don't know if this order of installation or the REinstallation of 'libusb' have any influence but I did what I read)
After this I could mount a USB into the virtual machine by adding hardware: 'USB Host Device' and in the list select the device I want.
The bad part is that it's Hard Connected to the virtual machine so it won't be accessible to the host until the VM is shutdown or some other 'hacking' of it that I at this point don't know about.
Have had to connect a shared directory. all the time the last years so this is a faster way.
